# Thread Virtual Memory state

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, virtual-memory

As we all know in case of multiple threads each thread maintains it's separate stack and register state.

do they also maintain separate virtual memory state or it can be shared ?

I don't think there should be any problem in sharing virtual memory state between processes.

**EDIT :**

If thread doesn't maintain state then why not the third option of question 1 on the link  ( http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/19913 ) is not true ?

Comment: What do you mean by virtual memory state?

Comment: by virtual memory state i mean addresses in virtual memory that are allocated or free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each process has its own ***address space*** aka range of virtual addresses that the process can access. Each process can have multiple threads. So, yes all the threads in a process share the same address space. Note that this is the primary reason that variables can be shared across multiple threads of the same process without any special mechanism.
On the other hand one cannot share variables across two separate processes without using special mechanisms like ***Inter process communication*** because each process has its own address space.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, two threads can share the same virtual memory space. This is essentially (very superficially) the definition of threads as they relate to processes.

Answer (score 0):

They invariably share memory.  And it can and does cause a *lot* of problems.

(Check the "multithreading" tag, for starters.)  But multiple threads let you listen for lots of different input, *and* they let you make all those CPU cores earn their keep.

Comment: Problems.. and opportunities <g>  Communicating huge buffers of data between threads on producer-consumer queues is a trivial matter of queueing up their address, (or class instance if OO).  The source thread, once it has posted off the address/ref, can immediately allocate/malloc/new/depool another one to the same *object and start work on it, (unless you use C++ references instead of pointers and so prevent such simple reseating :).